# Homology shows $\mathbb Z\cong 0$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I am looking to show that there exists two chain complexes $C_*$ and $C'_*$ and a chain map between them $f_\#\colon C_*\to C'_*$ such that in degree $0$, the map $f_0\colon C_0\to C_0'$ is non-zero yet the induced map on homology is the zero map. My idea was to find a chain complex $C_0'$ such that its homology $H_0'=0$, and hence the induced map has to be zero.

So I took 
$$C_*:= 0\to 0\to \mathbb Z\\ C_*':=0\to\mathbb Z\stackrel{\operatorname{id}}\to \mathbb Z$$

The homology of the first chain is $H_0=\mathbb Z$, and since the second chain has an isomorphism $\operatorname{id}:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, then the homology of the second chain $H_0'=0$.  In particular, the identity map induces the zero map. Contradiction? If homology is functorial, the induced map on the identity must be the identity itself. What went wrong?

Comment: I changed the notation a bit to (hopefully) make the chains clearer. Feel free to revert it if you don't like it.

Comment: $C_*$ and $C_*'$ are different chain complexes, so any map between them can't be an identity map (in the sense of category theory). I think your error is that you assumed what you call an "identity map" is an identity in the sense of category theory.

Comment: Is degree zero the middle term? Both have homology zero there. Also, the map between the chains is not the identity map...

Comment: @anomaly Well it made it clearer where the degree 0 was.

Comment: @George: I've removed the trailing $\to 0$ since (I imagine) that's not supposed to be part of the complex; it makes it more clear that "degree $0$" is the rightmost term.

Comment: @AreaMan Oh my, I have made a terrible blunder, I forgot the whole chain map needed to be the identity!